# Modifying the border of a FlatStyle.Flat button in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, button, graphics

I was wondering if there was any way to change the border of a `FlatStyle.Flat` button (how it paints). I want to change the border of a `Flat` button to look like it is rounded, like so:

[image]

I want `button2` to have a similar border to `button1`, how the pixels in each corner have been removed. I have no idea how to do this or where to begin. If anyone could help me or put me in the right direction, please post here. Thanks!

Comment: Paint it yourself. There is no builtin property of the `FlatStyle` which does this.

Comment: @Rotem Hmm, I will try to find a way to draw the parent's `BackColor` in each of the four corners, so it will appear to be rounded. Do you think that this will work?

Comment: There is more than that going on in the reference you posted. Would look better if you drew the border yourself. Here is an example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14275/Rounded-Corners

Comment: Thanks. I will have a go at drawing the border myself, that way I can also modify it further. Could you please post this comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Peter already answered pretty much the same thing, I think you should accept his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a [GraphicsPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) with rounded edges as border for that button. You'd have to draw it yourself though - WinForms doesn't have WPF's Border control.

Answer (score 1):

Import a dll like:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [DllImport("Gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateRoundRectRgn")]
    private static extern IntPtr CreateRoundRectRgn
    (
    int nLeftRect, // x-coordinate of upper-left corner
    int nTopRect, // y-coordinate of upper-left corner
    int nRightRect, // x-coordinate of lower-right corner
    int nBottomRect, // y-coordinate of lower-right corner
    int nWidthEllipse, // height of ellipse
    int nHeightEllipse // width of ellipse
    );

    public Form1()
    { etc.....................
```

Then in your button's paint event add:

```
button1.Region = System.Drawing.Region.FromHrgn(CreateRoundRectRgn(0, 0, button1.Width, button1.Height, 7, 7));
```

You can change the 'sevens' to the radius you like.